# not able to display textview

Tags: android, textview

I got stuck in such a silly situation, that i am not able to get rid of it. Textviews at the bottom of "Title" and at the bottom of "Notes" are not displayed when viewing in eclipse Graphical layout.

Check the image below:

[image]

And this is the code for it:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/black_glossy"
    tools:context=".TaskDetails" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayoutTaskDetailsTopBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@android:color/black" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="35dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:src="@drawable/details" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewTaskDetailsScreenTitle"
            style="@style/screen_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView1"
            android:text="Task details" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageViewTaskDetailsDone"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:src="@drawable/done_utton" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/viewTaskDetails"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayoutTaskDetailsTopBar"
        android:background="#33b5e5" />

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/viewTaskDetails"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="20dp" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Title : "
                android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewTaskDetailsTitle"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Title"
                android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
                android:textSize="17dp"
                android:textStyle="italic" />

            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Priority : "
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
                    android:textSize="20dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textViewTaskDetailsPriority"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="priority"
                    android:textStyle="italic"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:textSize="17dp" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Time : "
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
                    android:textSize="20dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textViewTaskDetailsTime"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="time"
                    android:textStyle="italic"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:textSize="17dp" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Notes : "
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
                    android:textSize="20dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textViewTaskDetailsNotes"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textStyle="italic"
                    android:text="No notes available."
                    android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
                    android:textSize="17dp" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView5"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Status : "
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
                    android:textSize="20dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textViewTaskDetailsStatus"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="status"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:textStyle="italic"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
                    android:textSize="17dp" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageViewTaskDetailsStarted"
                    android:layout_width="35dp"
                    android:layout_height="35dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:src="@drawable/play_deactivated" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageViewTaskDetailsAwaited"
                    android:layout_width="35dp"
                    android:layout_height="35dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:src="@drawable/pause_deactivated" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageViewTaskDetailsCompleted"
                    android:layout_width="35dp"
                    android:layout_height="35dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:src="@drawable/finished_deactivated" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Now, the text below "Title" is displayed while running the app because the data to be displayed will always be present. But i have "Notes" field as optional, it may or may not contain notes, hence as default it should display "No notes available.", as coded in xml.

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You have set orientation to vertical

Try changing

android:orientation="vertical"

to

android:orientation="horizontal"

Or you can also remove this attribute as the default orientation of Linear Layout is "horizontal"

Answer (score 0):

Problem is with your textcolor. So change the color of it and then try.

I am getting correct text . Below is the my graphical layout image.
[image]

Comment: I dont really understand why its not showing in Graphical Layout. Other textviews are also set in the same way, as the one which is not displayed, below notes.

Comment: I've never came across such a critical situation.

Comment: for me its working know.. what version of adt you are using ?

Comment: Working with eclipse since.

Comment: i am aslo checked with eclipse only for me its worked.. so that only captured the image.